# Post story problem- facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml

here is the code of index page

```
<a href="click.php" target= 'blank'>click Here to post story</a>
```

Click.php contains

```
    <?php 

     $app_id = "XXXXXXXX";

     $canvas_page = "XXXXXXXX";

     $message = "My story";

     $feed_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
            . "&message=" . $message;

     if (empty($_REQUEST["post_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $feed_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
        echo ("Feed Post Id: " . $_REQUEST["post_id"]);
     }
  ?>
```

Now my problem is, when i click on "click here to post story" link on main page, it directs the browser to another page where the post story box opens while I want to open this box in an iframe over the same page which usually happens in most of the applications.

here are the snap shots
My box opens like this[image]

but i want to open it like this in a light box
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this from the server side as your response will overwrite the current page.

You need to do this from the client side using javascript's "httpRequest" method to get your data from the server, or, better still use one of the well supported javascript toolkits like dojo, YUI, prototype etc. which will wrap the httpRequest function in a nice object and in addition provide some nifty UI classes to implement your pop out box.